# 27 inch monitor desktop not full size LG 27EA33V 1920x1080 DPI?

Tags: 12.10, kde, monitor

I just switched to a 27" full HD monitor from a 24" full HD monitor. However, the kubuntu 12.10 desktop appears with a black border all round.
I do not have an `xorg.conf` and the output of 
`xrandr` is :

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1920
DFP1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 337mm

output of xdpyinfo | grep -B2 resolution :
screen #0:
  dimensions:    1920x1080 pixels (508x285 millimeters)
  resolution:    96x96 dots per inch
```

How can I fix this ? Is it to do with DPI ?

Comment: What's the native resolution of your new monitor? Can you tell us the model? It seems that your graphics card (probably because of the driver) is limited to 1920x1920, so if your native resolution is bigger than that, we have a problem. Can you tell us your graphic card model too? Issue this command and paste the output: `lshw -c display`

Comment: [The monitor is a 1920x1080 model](http://www.lg.com/es/monitores/lg-27EA33V/technical-specifications).

Comment: Oops, didn't see that on the title.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds quite strange.  Your monitor is a 1920x1080 model and your graphics mode appears to be 1920x1080, so everything seems like it should be correct.

Troubleshooting steps:

- Make sure you are connecting to your monitor via an HDMI or DVI cable.  Don't use an old-style analog cable or anything else (like s-video).
- If you have an Nvidia card and you're using the proprietary driver, see if you can go through the `nvidia-xconfig` process again to generate a new xorg.conf.
- See if your monitor has, in its menu, options for adjusting overscan or scaling the display.

Comment: The script generating the xorg.conf is called `nvidia-xconfig`, not `nvidia-settings`.

Comment: Thanks Jorge.  But nvidia-settings is also capable of generating an xorg.conf, though it's less useful.  nvidia-xconfig is indeed the one I meant to say.